# Why is not necessary a cast for this C# function?

Tags: c#, casting, int, short

Using C#; I just realized, declaring `noValueNumber` as `const int` and returning it from this `short` function.
Why there is not an error message, like:

> Can't convert exxpression type `int` to return type `short`

```
    public static short ValueFromString(string onlyNumbersString)
    {
        if (onlyNumbersString.Length == 0)
        {
            const int noValueNumber = 999;

            return noValueNumber; // ¿...? 
        }

        return Int16.Parse(onlyNumbersString);
    }
```

Shouldn't be necessary a cast?, or there is, but hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) mentions that:

> You cannot implicitly convert nonliteral numeric types of larger storage size to short [...]

A (constant) value that fits `short` though is OK with implicit conversion.

**Edit:** Found the proper (positive) documentation for your example, [Implicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), that states that:

> A constant expression of type int can be converted to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type.

Answer (score 1):

This is because compiler is wise enough to see that `999` is proper `short` value and it is `const` so it will not be changed (the usage of `noValueNumber` can be replaced in fact by this value simply). If you will try for example to return `40000` you will get an compilation error:

> Constant value '40000' cannot be converted to a 'short'

In other way, if you remove `const` you will get expected:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

In yet other words, if you decompile your orignal function, you get:

```
public static short ValueFromString(string onlyNumbersString)
{
    short result;
    if (onlyNumbersString.Length == 0)
    {
        result = 999;
    }
    else
    {
        result = short.Parse(onlyNumbersString);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is how compiler "sees" this code, and as you see, there is no `const int` here at all.

Comment: I see. Declaring a `const`, was just to show you the explicitness of returned value type in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's because you've defined the variable as `a constant` with a value 999 (which is a valid Int16 value), so it can easily work with that. If you'd remove `const` from the definition, it would stop working. Smart compiler :)

Answer (score 0):

`999` is a valid `short` number. Since you use `const int noValueNumber` (`const` being the key here), the name `noValueNumber` is used as an alias for `999`. During pre-compile processing, each occurrence of `noValueNumber` is replaced with `999`, so the compiled code is actually `return 999;`.